# What is a laser tuned driver?

Tags: headphones

Hunting for microphones with a good frequency response, I encountered USB headsets. These headsets apparently come with 'laser tuned drivers'; is anybody aware of of what a laser-tuned driver is in the context of noise cancelling microphones/headphones? What makes a laser-tuned driver a selling feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be Logitech branding. Try this link from Logitech http://www.logitech.com/en-us/70/6059

> **A better listening experience**
>
> You listen to a lot of things on your computer. Distortion shouldn’t be one of them. That’s where our headsets with laser-tuned drivers come in. They minimize distortion so you can hear what you want to hear—and not what you don’t.
>
> **Tuning out distortion**
>
> A driver, otherwise known as the speaker, is the device in your headset that converts PC audio signals into the sound you hear. Most are developed with acoustic measurements alone. But, because we use laser measurements, we can pinpoint potential distortion and eliminate more of it.
>
> With laser tuning, we analyze the physics behind the mechanical motion of each component of the driver. That analysis guides our design. And that means you hear your audio in crystal-clear detail—just the way you were meant to.

Comment: Out of curiosity; In addition to noise-cancellation feature, what should one look for in computer microphone to use for professional purpose?

Comment: I would consider: how noisy the room is - do you want a built in headphone/mic combination - USB, jack or a telephone if you are using VoIP? Generally, for normal office usage, spending over £10 (~$15) should be fine unless you want it for multiple people in a room taking into the one device

Comment: Well, there is a bit of babble to say nothing of other extraneous noises. Hardly acceptable when recording for a third-party though. Can headphone/mic combinations give the kind of performance desired for professional recording? Or would applying an FFT filter using something like Audacity be a better option?

Comment: If you're recording professionally for a third party, then you have to get it right at source - Quite simply: garbage in, garbage out! Yes, you'll need to a compression/limiter, EQ and even a very light reverb to get it better, but I think the issue is having a quiet room to start with.

Comment: Erm. Would a high-impedance mic reject distant sounds better in favour of my voice speaking into it?

Comment: Possibly but this is getting quite specialist now. If the quality has to be high, get a quiet room. If some noise bleed is OK, then a normal microphone should suffice. Equipment will only help so much, getting the setting right is the most important

Comment: Understood. Thank you for letting me take up so much of your time.

Comment: This answer does not answer the question any better than the nonsense marketing talk on Logitech website. It just quotes it.

Comment: @Henno, That is why it is in block quotes. To show it is a quote! It is also why I cited where I took the quote! To show where the quote came from! But well done on your observation I had a concern that my explicitly marked up answer was ambiguous in some way!